# Chrome 65 on Windows : Some colors are incorrecly displayed

Tags: google-chrome, colors, srgb

Chrome 65 for Windows has an endless issue with colors. It just display some of them differently than FF and IE. Even Chrome on MacOS does not have this problem.

See the picture here : [Left Chrome, Right Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGskW.png)

On the left, the color displayed on Chrome, on the right the color in FF. The color code is (0,187,187) with transparency of 0.7
In Paint, the color looks like the FF one.

I know I can switch chrome://flags/#force-color-profile to sRGB to get the right color back but I cannot do that on my customers' machine.

1. Is there a way to change the html page to force Chrome to display my color correctly ?
2. Do you guys know if it is considered as a bug by the Chrome team ? Because they don't seem to care much about such a big issue that has been lasting since Chrome 61.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. Chrome is going to read the color configuration file of your windows operating system. Firefox will not do it by default and use a sRGB setting.

So you must go to "Color Management" and change your default settings (see picture).

[change your settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lgN6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps:

1. open chrome
2. type url: chrome://flags
3. in the page find the , Force color profile and change settings default to sRGB and relaunch